# Washing athletic wear

Tags: clothing

I've bought some athletic clothing (eg: from under armour, colombian etc) and it seems so that the smell of sweat doesn't go after simple wash with room temperature water, hence I've been including washing powder.

Is this safe for the fabric?

Comment: Depends on the fabric and the washing powder. In general, laundry detergent is safe for laundry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, it depends. Some powders and laundry detergents can end up blocking the pores in the fabric, which makes it breath less. Also, if you have SPF type fabrics, it can damage the capability of the fabric to block UV rays.

I sweat heavily, and I have had good luck with rinsing tech fabrics in water as soon as possible after a workout, and washing with a gentle detergent that has no dyes or scents, and adding a sports specific detergent as well.

Another thing that you can try is a product called Clear Gear, which is a disinfectant spray originally developed for hockey equipment. I use it to spray down my sparring gear after classes, and it has greatly reduced the odors that I notice from my gear bags.

Answer (score -2):

Using washing powder to get rid of sweat smells from athletic clothing is a good idea. Washing powders are generally safe for fabrics, but remember to check the care instructions on the clothing label to ensure you're washing them correctly for the best result